# Send email with rake on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

I fail to move some ruby code from my model to a rake task. The code is as follows in my "Contact" model:

```
  def send_notification_to_contact
    UserMailer.notification_contact.deliver_now
  end
```

In my Mailer folder, I have:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def notification_contact
    contact = Contact.find(1)
    mail to: contact.email, subject: "subject of the email"
   end
 end
```

I am trying to move this simple code (which works) in a rake task. In a file lib/task/scheduler.rake I put

```
desc "Notify"
task :notify => :environment do
  contact = Contact.find(1)
  contact.send_notification_to_contact
end
```

I call the task by amending my model as follows:

```
def send_notification_to_contact
  system "rake notify"
end
```

When I call this method or use the command line

```
rake notify
```

nothing happens. This is not a problem related to rake as a simple line such as

```
 puts "test"
```

in the scheduler.rake file does trigger the string "test" in the server's log

Could anyone tell me why it does not work and what is the appropriate syntax to have the task works ? I guess I am not fully understanding how rake works and how it interacts with my Model / UserMailer class. Thanks.

Comment: I believe you can keep the code how you have it, but move the delivery of the email to ActiveJob. It's something worth researching.

Comment: Are you able to successfully run notification method manually from rails env?

Comment: When you amended `send_notification_to_contact` to call `rake notifiy` what happened to the contents of original method that used to call `UserMailer.notification_contact.deliver_now` ?  Is that code being called from anywhere?